# Inject form generated by form_for into variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm working on a method inside a helper that creates a form for the view. There is a variable inside that method that stores all the html that will be returned and displayed on the view.

```
def create_form
  html << "<h1>Big Name</h1>"

  html << form_for(ActivityComment.new, remote: true, url: "activity_comments/create") do |f|
            f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control"
            f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
            f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success"
          end
  return html.html_safe
end
```

Now, when I run the helper in the view it only displays the submit button. Here is the html generated.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="activity_comments/create" class="new_activity_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_activity_comment" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What's going on here? My assumption is that only the last method, `f.submit` is returned in the `form_for` block. But how would I fix it so that the entire form is displayed?

Comment: Try not having "html <<"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://juliankniephoff.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/using-form_for-in-helper-methods/ There is everything you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. It surprisingly worked I was scared the code would be deprecated.

Comment: I've checked it before.